# Вывод предыдущей строки

Tags: python

```
f = open('text.txt','r')
for line in f:
 print(line)
```

Открываю файл таким образом, перебирая строки одна за одной
как можно вывести текущую строку + прошлую строку
что то типа:

```
print(line[i],line[i-1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать это можно десятком разных способов. Ну, например, вот так:

```
a=[]
for line in f:
    if fl==0:
        fl=1
        a.append(line)
    else:
        a.append(line)
        print(a[0],a[1])
        del a[0]
```

Вместо del a[0] можно использовать a.pop(0).

Можно несколько сократить код, избавившись от флажка:

```
a=[]
fl=0
for line in f:
    a.append(line)
    if len(a) !=1:
        print(a)
        a.pop(0)
    else:
        continue
```

Вместо построчного ввода файла можно затянуть все его содержимое и тогда выводите что угодно.

Answer (score 3):

Еcть такой вариант:

```py
prev = "\n"
with open('text.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print("previous: ", prev, "current: ", line)
        prev = line

'''
previous:  
 current:  my text

previous:  my text
 current:  it's also 

previous:  it's also 
 current:  it's too ...

previous:  it's too ...
 current:  my tttext
'''
```

а еще вариант по примеру [@Stanislav Volodarskiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1281301/281034), с итераторами:

```py
from itertools import tee

def pairs(seq):
    it = tee(seq)
    next(it[1])
    for item in zip(*it):
        yield item

with open('text.txt','r') as f:
    for prev,line in pairs(f):
        print("previous: ", prev, "current: ", line)

# вывод такой же, только нет первой пары строчек
```

с учетом дополнений [@Stanislav Volodarskiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1281301/281034) получаем такую функцию:

```py
from itertools import tee

def pairs(seq):
    it = tee(seq)
    next(it[1], None)
    return zip(*it)
```

Comment: `for item in zip(*it): yield item` -> `return zip(*it)` - это даст очень быструю реализацию.

Comment: `next(it[1])` я бы завернул в `try` для правильной обработки пустой последовательности/файла.

Comment: Идея с `tee` классная.

Comment: `def pairs(seq):
    it1, it2 = itertools.tee(seq)
    next(it2, None)
    return zip(it1, it2)`

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, действительно можно сразу `zip` отдавать. Что интересно, предыдущий код работает без выкидывания StopIteration если передается [] в качестве параметра. Хорошо сообразили на 2 головы!

Comment: За отсутствие исключения отвечает `None` в `next(it2, None)`. И да, получилось красиво.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, я имею ввиду `def pairs(seq):
    it = tee(seq)
    next(it[1])
    for item in zip(*it):
        yield item` - без None

Comment: Без `None` есть исключение, но если вы тестируете только в цикле `for`, то оно от вас скрыто. Более корректный тест `list(pairs([]))`.

Comment: [нашел.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16465313/9210255)

Answer (score 1):

В стандартной библиотеке Питона нет способа вывести пары из последовательности значений. Я использую такую утилиту:

```
def pairs(seq):
    it = iter(seq)
    try:
        prev = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    for item in it:
        yield prev, item
        prev = item
```

Выглядит страшно, использовать просто:

> ```
> @>>> print(*pairs([1, 2, 3, 4]))
> (1, 2) (2, 3) (3, 4)
> ```

С файлом её можно использовать так:

```
with open('text.txt','r') as f:
    for line1, line2 in pairs(f):
        print(line1, line2)
```

Comment: [немного модернизировал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1281293/281034) вашу функцию.